# rails collection_select wrong number of argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine-plugins, collection-select

I have a user_inputs table where I am storing the device subscription statuses under a column sub_status and these subscription statuses I want as drop down options Under the same name. Now after selecting one option from the drop down I want to save the id of the status in **equipment_assets table** under a **column_name subscription_status** and display the status on the browser.
I am trying collection_select for it but its not working.

```
<div class="pluginESV_formfield">
<%= f.label :subscription_status %><br />
<%= collection_select  :sub_status,UserInput.all,:id, :subscription_status %></div>
```

this gives error, wrong number of arguments, Please help me with this.

here-

- :sub_status is the field which has the drop down options.
- UserInput is the model from which these status are coming.
- :id is the index of the sub_status from the user_inputs table
- :subscription_status is the column in the equipment_assets table where selected IDs will be stored. I am not getting what's wrong with the
  code.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: try `f.select :sub_status_id, options_for_select(UserInput.all.map{|ui| [ui.subscription_status, ui.id]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For table `equipment_assets` with field `subscription_status`, you need to update `collection_select` as below:

```
<%= collection_select :equipment_asset, :subscription_status, UserInput.all, :id, :sub_status %>
```

As per the `collection_select` syntax, i.e.,

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

you missed the `object` argument which is why you got the error as `wrong number of arguments`. Its a mandatory argument as it helps to form `select` HTML element with proper `id` and `name` so that upon submission of form the selected value of `select` drop down will be passed in params hash correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but its still giving error, with f.collection_select it gives 
-:Error (undefined method `merge' for :subscription_status:Symbol)
and without f. it gives Error (undefined method `subscription_status' for #<UserInput id: 1, sub_status: "Subscribed">)

Comment: With `f.collection_select` you are not supposed to use `object` BUT with `collection_select` you must provide `object`. In your question you mentioned `collection_select`.

Comment: As per the error message, your field name is `sub_status` and not `subscription_status `. Hence, the symbol error. See my updated answer.

Comment: yeah that worked, so now I can see the  drop down options, but the table where I want to save the selected status has this field subscription_status. so on submit the selected input is going no-where.

Comment: What it is the table name and the field name in which you want to store the selected value from drop down? Update your question with relevant details.

Comment: yeah that worked perfectly. And now My concept about collecion_select is also clear. thank you so much for the help.